# Pulling a Report of Donors with More than One Donation, Not Recurring

Tags: contributions, mailing, recurring-contributions

I would like to pull a report of all donors who have more than one contribution. This is slightly different than pulling a report on actual recurring donations. This is my workflow:

- When donors donate one time, they get a thank you card and a receipt
- If donors contribute again in the same year, I save the acknowledgement for the end of the year, and send a PDF listing all the contributions with a total in the form of a generated letter

I want to use the CiviCRM to generate the form letter, but want to exclude everyone that has donated one time, since they will have already received sufficient documentation and acknowledgement.

Any advice on how this can occur?

Comment: I'll save the question of generating the PDF letter that lists all contributions for another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might not already know [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension can give you info like 'how many' donations, and i expect via Search Builder you could then drill down to '> 1' on that field to find just those who have contributed more than once

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate the list of people who contributed more than one donation by searching for anyone that still hasn't received a thank you. Even though they received one thank you, the subsequent contributions were not marked as having received one.

I did an advanced search for anyone that:

- has not received a thank you
- is in the donor smart group

The donor smart group is anyone that has made a contribution that counts as a donation.